# cannot find findViewById() in CustomListView using Fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am designing an UI where my app has 3 tabs and i have created it using fragments and i third tab i need to display listview with text and images.I can able to display the list but when i wrote click listener to each item the app start to crash and now I have an error in cannot findViewById()function.I'll share my code with this .please hepl me out
**Contact.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.tutorialsbuzz.slidetablistview.R;

public class Contact extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {         

String[] member_names;
TypedArray profile_pics;
String[] statues;
String[] contactType;
List<RowItem> rowItems;
ListView mylistview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Member_names);
    profile_pics = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.profile_pics);
    statues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statues);
    contactType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contactType);

    for (int i = 0; i < member_names.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(member_names[i],
                profile_pics.getResourceId(i, -1), statues[i],
                contactType[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }
    mylistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    profile_pics.recycle();
    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position == 0) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ummy.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 1) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),ummy.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }



    if (position == 2) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ummy.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 3) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ummy.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

    if (position == 4) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ummy.class );
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.tutorialsbuzz.slidetablistview.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context; 
List<RowItem> rowItems;

CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView profile_pic;
    TextView member_name;
    TextView status;
    TextView contactType;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);

        RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
        holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
        holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getContactType());

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Contact.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout     `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getView()` to fetch your view. This method returns the root view for the fragment. With this you can call `findViewById()`. Or do as follows

```
ListView mylistview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, container, false);
     mylistview = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return v;
}
```

`getView() method` :- Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

Use `getView()` method inside your `onActivityCreated` to find your view as follows

```
myListVIew = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Answer (score 0):

change you getView mehtod in adapter like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
        holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
        holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
        holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getContactType());

    return convertView;
}
```